# Error Building Android Project in Unity 2019.1f31

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, dex

I am trying to build my Android project in Unity 2019 and get this error at the end of the build process:

Build failure

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to 
process /Users/spin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files- 
.1/com.android.support.support-fragment-2 
6.1.0.aar/ccd5e1b70db7ab174f18c2e28670dc6a/jars/classes.jar See the 
Console for details.
```

In older versions on Unity, I used the Internal option as the build system, but 2019 version does not have that. So it looks like it uses the Gradle which I don't know much about.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: OK I updated it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to download and install JDK, SDK then accurate the path then -> go to preferences -> go to external tool and then accurate the JDK, SDK file folder in unity android build setting
2. then make sure your android connected with your PC and build your unity android app in your mobile

in addition, you can download unity current version android build to support your problem will be solved easily 
GD-Developer Sohaib Kh thanks